# Why most Gods are symbolised based on living things.?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, scripture, puranas, worship

Why most Gods are symbolised based on living things.?

we see shiva vishnu all in human form.

Comment: It is because the original form of God is formless! He is nameless! For the masses, it is very difficult to worship the one who is formless, the one who is nameless.

Comment: Don't u think, giving the form of living being we are making him mortal just like any other being

Comment: No, we are just symbolising the infinite into a form that we can worship. Also, they look like human beings but that doesn't mean they are human beings! We have mortal body, they don't have.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria God is both "with form and formless". God is everything in the universe. Its been said that  god would come in various  forms in different  lokas

Comment: @sysinit Yeah I know that.

Answer (score 1):

the form is for us to look upon and meditate.all forms we see are actually aspect encompassed by God. this is clearly explained in vishwaroopa darshana yoga in bhagavad githa by krishna.(krishna here symbolises the supreme lord.he is personifcation of paramathma).thus, God expressed in human forms/animal forms or other perceivable forms can be understood as God revealed to us in certain asppects for us to meditate, or contemplate; or God revealing a himself in a form encompassed by him that we can pereeive.this is why i think is the reason why God is generally in these forms.

Comment: You should cite sources for your answers

Comment: .rig veda 1/164/46 says "to him we call as indra,vayu,agni etc.".that is, ye "one being" is called in various names and forms. now, th fact tht God is all encompassing is present in bhagavad githa chapter 11, where arjuna sees all forms and manifestatons in the body of God.this is because God is all encompassing,all frms and manifestations are present in him.further, there is no need for extra sources because this is a basic fact.to all a person, we just need to tap one part encompassed by a being.thus to invoke God, we just need to call him through just a form. a

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is easier for the mind to relate to a friendly, human form as compared to abstract formlessness. Sri Sri Ravi Shankar narrates this in the context of *Arjuna*:

> ...Even Arjuna did not want god to be in a very powerful form, in the
> infinite form. He said, “Oh, no! No! Enough, enough! You show me your
> simple form, your human form!
>
> In the eleventh chapter of the Bhagavad
> Gita, when Krishna showed his infinite form to Arjuna, he showed his
> true form. Krishna said, “Inside me you see the sun, moon, stars,
> fire, earth, and all the elements. The ocean, everything you see
> inside of me. Close your eyes, I’ll show you with your inner eye,”
>
> And
> Arjuna got so shaken, he was so afraid, he said, “Oh no! You look good
> to me as a friend, somebody whom I can talk to nicely, this is enough
> for me. Don’t show me that! Be a simple form, a human form. I love you
> in the human form. You come to me in the Human form!...”

Excerpts from a talk: [www.dvorahji.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/mylittleguru.pdf](http://www.dvorahji.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/mylittleguru.pdf)